# Turbolinks page:fetch not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm working on an enterprise application which made with **Ruby on Rails** actually I'm working for the maintenance on the web app, so I want to add a **spinner** on this application instead of **Turbolinks ProgressBar**, so on the initial stage I'm testing the `page:change` & `page:receive` working but those is not working, look how I tested

```
$(document).on('page:fetch', function() {
    alert("OK");
});

$(document).on("page:receive", function(){
    alert("OK");
});
```

also

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:fetch', function() {
    alert("OK");
});

$(document).on("turbolinks:receive", function(){
    alert("OK");
});
```

also, browser console is clean no any error.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the latest [**`Turbolinks`**](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#observing-navigation-events) [**`Full List of Events`**](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events) then it should be like this use `turbolinks:request-start` instead `turbolinks:fetch` and `page:fetch`, `request-start` for `receive`

```
$(function() {
    document.addEventListener('turbolinks:request-start', function() {
        alert("OK");
    });

    document.addEventListener("turbolinks:request-end", function(){
        alert("OK");
    });
});
```

I have used this for mine and it's working.

Hope it will help you.